# Allow HTML tags for Bank Transfer Payment Method Instructions

Tags: magento2.3

I want to add some instructions with HTML tags to style content for the instructions text.

When I'm adding tag in the textarea but it's displaying tags on the frontend not converting HTML tags to output.

> magento\vendor\magento\module-offline-payments\view\frontend\web\template\payment\banktransfer.html

```
<p data-bind="html: getInstructions()"></p>
```